# Unexpected nil in JSON strings

Tags: json, swift, null

I parse JSON in my application and some of the JSONs have `nil` values which I handled. However, the app still shows me the error that JSON contains `nil` values. My code:

```
struct Response : Decodable {
let articles: [Article]
 }

struct Article: Decodable {

let title: String
let description : String
let url : String
let urlToImage : String
}
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
     guard let data = data else { return }
     do {
     let article =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self , from : data)
     for i in 0...article.articles.count - 1 {
         if type(of: article.articles[i].title) == NSNull.self {
             beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append("")
         } else {
             beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append(article.articles[i].title)
         }
if type(of : article.articles[i].urlToImage) == NSNull.self {
                beforeLoadNewsViewController.newsImages.append(newsListViewController.newsImages[newsListViewController.newsIndex])

                    } else {
                        
                        
                    let url = URL(string: article.articles[i].urlToImage ?? "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b77fe464cfc445da9003a5383a3e1acf.jpg")
                    
                        
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

                    if url != nil {

                    //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                        let img = UIImage(data: data!)
                    beforeLoadNewsViewController.newsImages.append(img!)

                    } else {
                beforeLoadNewsViewController.newsImages.append(newsListViewController.newsImages[newsListViewController.newsIndex])

                        }
```

This is the error running the app:

> FC91DEECC1631350EFA71C9C561D).description], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

#### Note:

This JSON works with other urls that don't have `nil` values.

and here is the json

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "source": "entertainment-weekly",
    "sortBy": "top",
    "articles": [
    {
        "author": null,
        "title": "Hollywood's Original Gone Girl",
        "description": null,
        "url": "http://mariemcdonald.ew.com/",
        "urlToImage": null,
        "publishedAt": null
    },
    {
        "author": "Samantha Highfill",
        "title": "‘Supernatural’: Jensen Ackles, Jared Padalecki say the boys aren’t going ‘full-mope’",
        "description": "",
        "url": "http://ew.com/tv/2017/10/18/supernatural-jensen-ackles-jared-padalecki-season-13/",
        "urlToImage": "http://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/supernatural-season-13-episode-1.jpg?crop=0px%2C0px%2C2700px%2C1417.5px&resize=1200%2C630",
        "publishedAt": "2017-10-18T17:23:54Z"
    },
    {
```

Comment: You’ll have to share the relevant JSON...

Comment: what more thing you need?

Comment: The JSON you’re trying to decide which returns this error...

Comment: news api for entertainment weekly JSon

Comment: Please include the JSON itself in your post.

Comment: ok I added this and edited my question so you can see null values in json

Comment: Can you provide the definitions for the various types (classes) you're using? You're apparently not allowing null values for one of the properties of articles.

Comment: ok wait please I will update question

Comment: I used ? after variables But I will receive fatal Error

Comment: apart from nullable values, another stupid reason for having that error could be simply getting malformed json (or 404)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is quite clear. `JSONDecoder` maps `NSNull` to `nil` so the decoder throws an error if it's going to decode a `nil` value to a non-optional type.

The solution is to declare all affected properties as optional.

```
let title: String
let description : String?
let url : String
let urlToImage : String?
```

or customize the decoder to replace `nil` with an empty string.

And because `JSONDecoder` maps `NSNull` to `nil` the check `if ... == NSNull.self {` is useless.

Edit:

Don't use ugly C-style index based loops use

```
 let response =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self , from : data)
 for article in response.articles {
      beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append(article.title)
 }
```

PS: But why for heaven's sake do you map the article instance to – apparently – separate arrays? You got the `Article` instances which contain everything related to one article respectively.

Comment: so I used this But I will receive Fatal Error

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi In which line?

Comment: beforeLoadNewsViewController.descArray.append(article.articles[i].description!)

Comment: Then the decoding works fine. Is `titleArray` in `beforeLoadNewsViewController` initialized?

Comment: what are you mean ? Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: I don't think its related because the print(article.articles[i].description!) will cause Fatal Error to before that

Comment: But the print of print(article.articles[i].description!) before that line will cause Fatal error too

Comment: I see, `descArray` is not mentioned in the code. But since `description` can be `nil`, don't forced unwrap it. Write `print(article.articles[i].description ?? "n/a")`

Comment: the image has problem now can you edit your codes for image too?

Comment: What codes? The image does not appear in **your** code. Once again: **Never** forced unwrap optionals which can be `nil`

Comment: ok now every things looks good the problem is just images for when the image url is empty I want to use image in my app

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read your mind. Please edit your question and add the relevant code and a description.

Comment: look now every things are ok I just need to know how to get url of the images that i copied into my application to show them instead of nil images in my application and I edited the code for images to show

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I cannot comment yet. But why don't you test for "null" the way, you did at the URLSession data check, with the [guard-statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement)?

It would then look like:

```
guard let title = article.articles[i].title else {
    beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append("")
    return
}
beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append(title)
```

You try to parse a JSON structure here, in case the JSON structure would not fit to your needs, you still expect it to have the according attributes.

Could you also provide your JSON structure and how your decoding

```
try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self , from : data)
```

looks like?

Comment: I don't have any problems with other urls this son is for news api and in Entertainment Weekly api I have problem because the son contains nil values - one more thing I used your codes But the app won't allow me to run because of guard let line

Comment: why not simply `beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append(article.articles[i].title ?? "")` or without the loop using map  `beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray = article.articles.map{$0.title ?? ""} ` and if you don't want the empty strings in your array use `article.articles.flatMap{$0.title}` instead

Comment: I used beforeLoadNewsViewController.titleArray.append(article.artic‌​les[i].title ?? "") but no difference still there is problem